# Is it possible to find out the value of given variable in the following question?

Tags: numerical-methods

It is given that $u_1 = 1, u_2+u_3 = 6$ and $u_4+u_5+u_6+u_7+u_8 = 30$. What is the approximate value of $u_4$ when computed by using Lagrange's interpolation formula?

1) $7$

2) $6$

3) $5$

4) $4$

I have no idea how to start with?

Comment: Can you explain it plz?

Comment: The question is written pretty poorly. Is $u_i$ the value of a function at $x=i$? Perhaps there is context that we are missing.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a normal interpolation problem; ordinarily you would be given exact values of $u$ at each of several values of $x$ and then interpolate them from there.

Comment: Ys i also thinks the same.